# Running Bundler on Windows - permission denied on /dev/null

Tags: ruby, windows, bundler

I'm trying to set up a Ruby dev environment on Windows. So far it's fairly "vanilla", that is,  it pretty much only consists of Ruby (1.9.1), Bundler (1.3.5) and a few random gems.

Now, whenever I try to run Bundler, I get the following exception:

```
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:544:in `initialize': Permission denied - /dev/null (Errno::EACCES)
```

Checking the source code, I found that Bundler determines that you're running Windows by trying to access /dev/null and then rescuing Errno::ENOENT ("No such file or directory"). I tried patching it to also rescue Errno:EACCES ("Permission denied"), and voila - it seems to run just fine.

I tried running the shell in elevated mode, but it still threw Errno:EACCES.

**My question is simply this:** Am I missing something? Or is this a bug in Bundler?

(for reference, I'm running on Windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/null` is a special file and is typically used for disposing of unwanted output streams of a process, or as a convenient empty file for input streams in *nix operating systems. It's not there in Windows.

If bundler is not checking on which operating system it's trying to use /dev/null then surely it's a problem at their end. To get things working without moving much you can use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html).

Comment: Yeah, I know about /dev/null :) It sounds right that it's a problem on Bundler's end. I saw a snippet of code from a different version of the source file in question, and there it evaluated a "is windows" variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on Windows 7.
I'v observed the issue "Errno:EACCES ("Permission denied")" for c:/dev/null 
The directory c:/dev  created (no "null" file) and problem resolved.